# an error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3) and bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

home/xxxx/Desktop/dsp-manage/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version
(Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
from /home/xxxx/Desktop/dsp-manage/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile' from extconf.rb:32:in` '

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/home/xxxx/Desktop/dsp-manage/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/xxxx/Desktop/dsp-manage/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/xxxx/Desktop/dsp-manage/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
therubyracer

Comment: `therubyracer` installs on Mac are notoriously difficult. Do you actually need v8 in your app?

Comment: Try these tips: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/868b64cd60ab2d51ab24e7bf384da1ca&ved=2ahUKEwjghYfDgsn6AhXkH0QIHXwdDuoQFnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3_D6y44RULI2klZ5xmH7aS